# hybrid attribute expression: aggregate attribute on many side of one to many

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

assuming these models:

```
class A(Base):
    ...
    targets = relationship("B", back_populates='a')
    ...

class B(Base):
    ...
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    a = relationship("A", back_populates='targets')
    attr = Column(ENUM('a', 'b', 'c', name='options'), default='a')
    ...
```

How could I write a `hybrid_attribute.expression` to return True for all `A`s where any related `B`s have an `attr` attribute value in `('b', 'c')`? (This should also return False if there are no related `B`s.)

This gets me halfway there:

```
# hybrid_attribute expression in A model
@example_attr.expression
def example_attr(cls):
    return case(
        [
            (
                B.attr.in_(('b','c')),
                True
            )
        ],
        else_=False
    )
```

But then how do I group them by `A.id` where if any related `B`s are `True` then the `example_attr` column value for that `A` row is `True`?

I want top be able to do: `session.query(A).filter(A.example_attr.is_(True)).all()`

EDIT 1:

This SQL seems to provide the desired result:

```
select a.id, coalesce(bool_or(a_id_b_attr.status), false)
    from a left outer join (
        select b.a_id as a_id, b.attr in ('b', 'c') as status from b
    ) as a_id_b_attr
    on a.id = a_id_b_attr.a_id group by a.id;
```

But I am having a slight issue referring to the aliased fields in the subquery:

```
sub = db.session.query(B.a_id.label('a_id'), B.attr.in_(('b', 'c')).label('status')).subquery() 
db.session.query( 
    A.id,  
    db.func.coalesce( 
        db.func.bool_or(sub.status),  
        False 
    ) 
).\ 
outerjoin(sub, A.id == sub.key_id).\ 
group_by(A.id)
```

Which throws an `AttribubteError` seeing as `sub` doesn't have any of the aliased attributed.

Comment: You'd use the `c` namespace attribute to access the columns of a derived table (subquery), so `sub.c.a_id` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How could I write a `hybrid_attribute.expression` to return `True` for all As where any related Bs have an attr attribute value in `('b', 'c')`? (This should also return `False` if there are no related Bs.)

You could use an EXISTS subquery expression:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    targets = relationship("B", back_populates='a')

    @hybrid_property
    def example_attr(self):
        return any(b.attr in {'b', 'c'} for b in self.targets)

    @example_attr.expression
    def example_attr(cls):
        return exists().\
            where(and_(B.a_id == cls.id,
                       B.attr.in_(['b', 'c']))).\
            correlate(cls)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.id'))
    a = relationship("A", back_populates='targets')
    attr = Column(ENUM('a', 'b', 'c', name='options'), default='a')
```

This does not rely on any grouping, but correlation, and can be used directly in your desired query:

```
# Note that comparing booleans with booleans is a bit redundant
session.query(A).filter(A.example_attr).all()
```

Postgresql is able to rewrite (some) queries using correlated EXISTS subquery expressions to [semijoins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_(%E2%8B%89)(%E2%8B%8A)), so the usual performance notes about correlation may not apply.

If you'd like to approach this using grouping, you'd use [`bool_or`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.25.4.2.2.7.1.1) and explicit joins:

```
session.query(A).\
    join(B).\
    group_by(A.id).\
    having(func.bool_or(B.attr.in_(['b', 'c']))).\
    all()
```

Postgresql allows selecting all columns of `A` in this grouped query even though they are not aggregate expressions, because they are functionally dependent to the grouping column(s) – in other words `A.id` determines the selected columns.

Comment: for the instance method, is there a better way than using `any` and iterating over the related objects? would something like: `self.targets.filter(B.attr.in_(('b', 'c'))).first() is not None` be more performant?

Comment: It might, but that'll depend on are you eager loading etc. In the end the difference might not be that big, but again that depends on your data. Note that the expression you've come up with will require that the relationship is configured as [dynamic](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders). I added the instance method just for completeness sake, though I supposed that you had an implementation for it already.

Comment: Btw. this is a great chance to reflect on how awesome SQL DBMS are, in this respect; they do these kinds of choices for you all the time, i.e. what is the best / good enough way to get the result you want.